# Box around OSM plot in R

Tags: r, openstreetmap

Can anyone put a box around an OpenStreetMap plot in R?  `box` doesn't fit to the map itself, and `rect` doesn't plot anything at all..

```
require(OpenStreetMap)    
m = openmap(c(52,-1), c(51,1), zoom=8, type='osm')
par(mai=rep(.2,4))
plot(m, removeMargin=F)
box()
rect(-1, 51, 1, 52, border='black', lwd=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`box()` plots a box around the whole plot area, which apparently includes some white space.

The problem with  `rect` is that the coordinates are not as you'd expect: check this by adding some axes to the plot. The correct boundary coordinates can be obtained from the `m` object itself: `m$bbox`, see `str(m)`. Use these to draw your rectangle like this:

```
require(OpenStreetMap)    
m = openmap(c(52,-1), c(51,1), zoom=8, type='osm')
# par(mai=rep(.2,4))

plot(m, removeMargin=F)

# add axes to check coordinates, uncomment to see for yourself
# axis(1); axis(2)

p1 = m$bbox$p1 # bottom left
p2 = m$bbox$p2 # top right
rect(xleft=p1[1], ybottom=p1[2], xright=p2[1], ytop=p2[2], xpd=NA, lwd=2, border='red')
```

Comment: D'oh. Of course the coordinates are in Mercator. Thusly `projectMercator(c(51,52), c(-1,1))` should also get the bbox, although your method is probably more reliable. Thanks koekenbakker.